# The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have configured maven-surefire-plugin and jacoco plugin to generate the junit code coverage report. However, I am getting 2 different error in 2 different scenarios. Can you please have a look on below errors and help me? Any help is really appreciable.

When I keep my forkCount as 0(zero) in maven-surefire-plugin configuration then all tests are executed successfully but jacoco report is not generated. It gives me message as "Skipping JaCoCo execution due to missing execution data file."

When I keep my forkCount as 1 in maven-surefire-plugin configuration then I get the below error,
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 1
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:671)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)

If required you can refer the below pom.xml file to know the cause of concern,

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    com.testmodule
    test-module
    1.0.6
    Test Module

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
    <tomcat.version>8.5.4</tomcat.version>
    <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    <maven.build.timestamp.format>yy.MM</maven.build.timestamp.format>
    <powermock.version>2.0.0-beta.5</powermock.version>

    <!-- Sonar-JaCoCo properties -->
    <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
    <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
</properties>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <!-- START Spring boot dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.testmodule</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-module-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20180813</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- START JUnit Test dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.tempus-fugit</groupId>
        <artifactId>tempus-fugit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END JUnit Test dependencies -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
                <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
            </configuration>        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                 <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                      <configuration>
                          <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                          <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>                                 
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                      <id>jacoco-report</id>
                      <phase>verify</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                      </goals>                        
                 </execution>           
            </executions>
        </plugin>   
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
              <mainClass>com.testmodule.module</mainClass>
              <finalName>test-module</finalName>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
             </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Added for java 10 -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <version>6.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>test-module</finalName>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>resources/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- append to the packaging phase. -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal> <!-- goals == mojos -->
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                      <echo file="version.txt">${maven.build.timestamp}.${BUILD_NUMBER}</echo>
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Implementation-Version>${maven.build.timestamp}.${BUILD_NUMBER}</Implementation-Version>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>  
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to upgrade jacoco version as you use java10. you can use JaCoCo version 0.8.3 It seems to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update the surefire plugin to 2.17